# Gas leak rate from a pipe

Tags: chemical-engineering, gas

I am trying to find out how to calculate the leak rate of gas (composed of mostly methane at around 30degC and 150psi) from a pinhole leak (~5mm) to the atmosphere in a pipe where you do not have the duration of the leak or the flow rate in the pipe.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you measure this, or this is purely a calculation? You likely have to assume something about the flow, e.g. that is an orifice